# How to display data from Postgresql query into a Pie ChartJs in Django Framework?

Tags: django, pie-chart

I am working in a Django Project and I would like to show some data from PostgreSql to a Pie ChartJs, but I do not find a way, here my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from appclientes.models import Cliente, Municipio
from django.db.models import Count
```

## Create your views here.

def pie_chart_view(request):
results =     Cliente.objects.values('municipio__nombre_municipio').annotate(clientes_adsl=Count('id'))
nombres_municipio = [result['municipio__nombre_municipio'] for result in results]
totals = [result['clientes_adsl'] for result in results]
print(nombres_municipio,totals)
print(results)

```
context = {
    'results': results 
}

return render(request, "appclientes/pie_chart.html", context)`
```

``
The QuerySet that I obtained with the sentence print(results) is correct and I here you are my Template where I render the pie:

{% load static %}

```
{{ title }}



   
     <canvas id="pieChart" width="400" 
     height="100">


<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('pieChart').getContext('2d');

    var data = {
        labels: [{% for result in results %}{{ result.nombre_municipio }}{% endfor %}],
        datasets: [{
            data: [{% for result in results %}{{ result.clientes_adsl }}{% endfor %}],
            backgroundColor: [
                '#FF0000',
                '#00FF00',
                '#0000FF',
                '#FFFF00',
                '#00FFFF',
                '#FF00FF',
            ],
        }]
    };

    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: data,
    });
</script>
```

`

But wehe I call the URL it does not show anything just a painted red circle with nothing else. When I inspect in the data appear a number 98343255114 I do not know what does mean.
Thank you.

I would like to view the name of the places and the amount of Customers for every places in the pie ChartJs. Thanks.